Blazor two way binding and on value changed event in the parent
What's is the recommended way to trigger a callback in the parent control using two way databinding when a property changed in the child control?
I have tried following but it's not triggering HandleValueChanged. Is there a conventional way to trigger OnValueChanged in the parent?
Parent Component
@page "/parent"

<h3>Parent Component</h3>

<ChildComponent @bind-Value="parentValue" @bind-Value:after="HandleValueChanged" />

<p>Parent Value: @parentValue</p>

@code {
    private int parentValue = 0;

    private void HandleValueChanged()
    {
        // Handle the value change event here
        Console.WriteLine($"Value changed to: {parentValue}");
    }
}

Child Component
<h3>Child Component</h3>

<input type="number" @bind="Value" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}


How is OnValueChanged getting called in your child component?

OnValueChanged inside the child component never gets executed, which means that the parent component never gets informed about the new property value at all, not just that HandleValueChanged doesn't execute. You should also notice that <p>Parent Value: @parentValue</p> doesn't update to a newer value when the child's input element is changed.

Is there a conventional way to trigger OnValueChanged in the parent?

The child component needs to execute OnValueChanged (or, more correctly, the child component is the one that needs to execute ValueChanged.InvokeAsync()).
I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with the line Value = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());. It doesn't seem necessary when you're already binding Value.
Here's the updated child component code:
<input type="number" @bind="Value" @bind:after="OnValueChanged" />

private async Task OnValueChanged()
{
    await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
}

Instead of doing :after (and @bind) in the child, you could use the value= and onchange= attributes, but it would be your responsibility to update Value in the delegate. That's the point of :after - it still lets you do 2-way data binding (you don't need to manually update the property yourself) but you can still trigger a method to run after the binding is updated.

Thanks, that helps. Is there anyway to get rid of this from parent "@bind-Value:after="HandleValueChanged"" get a trigger automatically by using conventions? Or does parent always need it?

As I said in my last paragraph, the best you'd be able to do is hook up the input and event attributes manually. There is no "convention" like what you're thinking of. The only convention that exists is "if your component has a property "T Name" and a property EventCallback<T> NameChanged, then the caller of the component can instead of using those two entries directly can use @bind-Name."

That's why :after was added, because people were tired of being prevented from doing @bind because they couldn't call a function and have automatic 2 way binding done for them at the same time. Of course, if you do use :after, you have to name the function you want to call.

Sounds good, thank you.
